# Jekyll -- create another folder with similar functionality of _posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

I have a _posts folder that contains all my posts for my blog and projects. I'd like to separate the markdown files for my blog notes and project pages. For example, in addition to the built-in md -> HTML conversion for files in _posts, I'd like to have a _projects folder that contain my markdown files for individual project write-ups and build them into HTML when running jekyll serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `categories`. Here is a link discussing a similar problem : [Multiple _posts directories](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1819#issuecomment-30441840)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but it prompted a hacky idea I implemented, which works. I separated my notes and projects files into two subdirectories in _posts. From there, I added a layout tag to the front matter for each of these, which served to identify whether or not it was a note or project file. To display all projects in my projects overview page, I used this`{% for post in site.posts %}
 {% if post.layout == "project" and post.status == "in-progress" %}`

Comment: @JasonBak _posts folder shouldn't contain subdirectories.

Answer (score 8):

just define a `collections` key in your `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
```

[Official docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) for more info..

Answer (score 2):

By default Jekyll will ignore new folders with an underscore prefix, so you can't use `_projects`.

You can separate `_posts` in several folders, to have all your project files in a specific folder, create `projects/_posts` folder structure and move your project files inside `projects/_posts`, leaving blog posts in `_posts`.

Jekyll will generate each post and automatically assign the `project` **category** to them, so you can also generate different lists from your blog posts.